# How to pluck and display items from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Yelp type app. I have a table of restaurants, a table of dishes, and a join table between the two that I have named dishings (dish_id & restaurant_id). If a row in dishings exists, that means the restaurant carries that item.

I would like to add a menu to the restaurant show page, which lists out all the menu items associated with that restaurant.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `restaurant` model, add this association:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :dishes, join_table: :dishings
```

In your `dish` model, add this association:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :restaurants, join_table: :dishings
```

Then, to get all dishes for a restaurant:
    restaurant.dishes

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Running '<%= restaurant.dishes %> provides the following output: #<Dish::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fed63965700>'. Do you know what kind of command/loop I would need to successfully spit out dishes?

Comment: Now you have an array of dishes, that's good. Then you can do
<% restaurant.dishes.each do |dish| %>
(do something with `dish`)
<% end %>

Comment: Getting close! I'm still getting a NameError. Here's my flawed code: <% @restaurant.dishes.each do |dish| %>
      <%= dishes.dish.pluck(:dish_name) %>
      <% end %>

Comment: Use `<%=dish.dish_name%>`, should work if you have a `dish_name` property on your `dish`model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ÉricCôté. This worked great!

```
<% @restaurant.dishes.each do |dish| %> 
<%=dish.dish_name%> 
<% end %>
```